Praat pitch algorithm realization in python
I am interested in speech processing algorithms and want to experiment with python source code. Is there python realization for praat pitch estimation algorithm or similar algorithms based on autocorrelation function? I know about Parselmouth library but it is the wrapper over the C/C++ code. Thank you for any GitHub suggestions.
